# Notes system in database

Tags: database, ms-access, database-schema

I'm currently working on building an ERP/CRM database in Access 2013 to cover all non-financial aspects of running a business such as customer/supplier info, contacts, order and deliveries tracking, and that sort of thing.

We manufacture made-to-measure joinery products (windows, doors etc). One thing that I'm finding is that I'll need to have the ability to write notes about records in almost every table in the database. For example, I may want to write notes on the following tables:

- `tblAccount` which holds customer and supplier info, e.g. "This customer always has special glass".
- `tblDelivery` - "Customer has requested that driver parks at back of house on London Road".
- `tblQuote` - "Quote does not include timber cladding for steels - supplied by others".

etc. etc.

So currently I have a `tblNote` which has the following fields:

- `NoteID` - PK
- `AccountID` - FK to `tblAccount`
- `DeliveryID` - FK to `tblDelivery`
- `QuoteID` - FK to `tblQuote`
- Several more FKs to other tables which contain things I might need to keep notes on.
- `EnteredByUsedID` - FK to `tblUser` of the database user who entered the note onto the system.
- `EntryDate` - Date note was entered
- `NoteText` - the text of the note
- `CommTaskID` - Explained later - see below

When entering a new note, most of the FKs to other tables will be blank (except those which the note actually concerns). The notes will be viewed either on a subform, e.g. when browsing through customer accounts there will be a box which shows notes about that customer.

The reason for having notes in their own table is that each record in the database (e.g. a customer account) may need to have more than one note attached to it.

I also want to implement task assignment and tracking, and communication logging. For example when we receive a phone call from a prospective new customer asking for a quotation we would record that the call was received and when, the customer's contact details, note that they have requested a quote along with minor details about what they want quoted, plus flag it for action required either by a specific database user or with nobody specified. It might also be created as a

With this in mind I have `tblCommTaskLog` which has the following fields:

- `CommTaskID` - PK
- `CommMethodID` - FK to `tblCommMethod` which holds things like `Phone call`, `Fax`, `Email` and `In Person`.
- `AccountID` - account record of the person (customer/supplier) making the contact
- `EnteredByUserID` FK of user who entered this record.
- `EntryDate`
- `IsActionRequired` - Boolean
- `ActionRequiredByUser` - FK to user table to flag who needs to take action on this item (could be blank if this action can be completed by anybody).
- `ActionCompletedDate` - Date when the action was marked as completed.
- `ActionCompletedByUser` - Another FK to user table for user who completed task.

As seen above there is then a `CommTaskID` in the notes table which would allow you to create note records which contain any relevant notes about the communication or task.

Basically my question is: Is there a better way to go about this? Am I missing something? It seems a clunky way to go about things but I'm unable to come up with a better one which follows DB normalisation rules.

Comment: Instead of storing foreign keys in the notes table, why not do the other way around and store the primary key from notes, NoteID, as a nullable foreign key in all the tables that can have notes, like tblAccount?

Comment: I addressed this in the question: "The reason for having notes in their own table is that each record in the database (e.g. a customer account) may need to have more than one note attached to it". I need a one to many so that I can have many notes for each record if necessary.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Then I think you're on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concept sounds right to me.  I've had to integrate notes into an existing DB and you definitely only want one Notes table with a field that designates which table the note belongs to, and which Primary Key within that table the note is tied to.

So, I think maybe you want this:

- NoteID - PK
- **TableID - FK to a new table, which stores the names of your tables**
- **TablePK - FK to the Primary Key in the table referenced in TableID**
- Several more FKs to other tables which contain things I might need
  to keep notes on.
- EnteredByUsedID - FK to tblUser of the database user who entered the
  note onto the system.
- EntryDate - Date note was entered
- NoteText - the text of the note
- CommTaskID - Explained later - see below

This way, you'll know which table it belongs to, and which record in that table that it belongs to.

In a query, you can simply join TablePK to the key in your table, and filter TableID based on what table you're joining to.

Or, if you need to set up a relationship you can simply add a new field to all your tables with their TableID in it.

Comment: I've _sort of_ gone for this approach. Your answer made me realise that each note may need to refer to a number of different items, so while my note may primarily be about a `Quote` in `TblQuote`, I may also need to make reference to a some contact details in `TblContact`, so what I've got is a `PrimaryTableID` which links to a table storing the names of the different tables I'm taking notes about, if that makes sense. This way I can identify where that note needs to show up in my system interface.

Comment: Not every answer in a complex question like this is going to fit the exact bill, so I'm glad to have at least pushed you in the right direction while allowing you to edit the methodology to fit your project.  "Give a man a fish and he eats for a day, teach a man to fish and he eats for a lifetime."  :o)

Comment: Yeah that's what I figure too. I could have tried to explain the requirements in more detail but you get to the point where the more you explain the less sense it makes. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

Just an idea but would it make more sense to have a notes table for each table you want to make notes on?

TblCustomer
TblCustomerNotes

TblProduct
TblProductNotes

etc.

Comment: I don't think so, as then each of those notes tables would have the same fields except for the FK, and each table would need to be handled in its own specific form/code. Sounds like building/maintenance headache to me.